# WSO2 SAML SSO for different carbon versions

Tags: saml, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I'm trying to setup SAML based SSO for set of WSO2 products (all used by latest versions available for now):

- WSO2 Identity Server 4.5.0
- WSO2 Business Rules Server 2.0.0
- WSO2 ESB 4.7.0
- WSO2 Business Activiti Monitoring 2.4.0
- WSO2 Application Server 5.2.0

SSO works fine for BAM and AS, but failed for other servers (BRS, ESB).
I'm getting on IS side exception like:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[2013-11-01 22:16:26,830] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil} -  Error in constructing AuthRequest from the encoded String
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

nd
As I understand problem is: IS, AS and BAM all based on carbon 4.2.0 - and as result SSO working fine, but BRS and ESB latest versions based on older carbon (4.1.0 or 4.0.0) and there are compatibility problem in message encoding between different carbon versions.

Question - is it possible to fix somehow tools based on older carbon version to make it working with latest carbon 4.2.0 based IS 4.5.0?
Or, in general, how setup SAML SSO independently from each carbon (or even not carbon-based at all) service providers used?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a know issue. Identity Server 4.5.0 can not be used to do SSO with older carbon versions. This is due that SAML2 SSO authenticator in older carbon version is not complaint with IS 4.5.0 IDP. Actually there is some bug in the older versions. However there are some fixes for that. They can be found in public jiras (not sure). ESB and BRS are going to release soon, before end of Nov,  Therefore you can try with newer versions as they are also based on Carbon 4.2.0 platform,

Comment: Thanks for response. Is it possible to download / build newer versons of ESB / BRS before release? (I'd like to try them even understand their "beta" status)

Comment: You can download Alpha release of ESB 480 from here  https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/shafreen/ESB480/alpha/wso2esb-4.8.0.zip

Comment: Thank you. Is something similar available for new version of BRS?

Comment: @Asela - What could be the reason for error?
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Error when issuing the access token.  {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service}
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.opensaml.saml2.core.impl.ResponseImpl cannot be cast to org.opensaml.saml2.core.Assertion

Answer (score 0):

I am getting exactly same issue with same configuration.  @Asela as you mentioned, I can either go with ESB 4.8.0 (or) IS 4.1.0; but what kind of issues we'll have when we go for decentralized federated SAML2 IdP.

Is IS 4.1.0 is compatible with ESB 4.7.0, and is tested in decentralized federated SAML2 IdP?  If so, we would downgrade our IS to 4.1.0.

Comment: You can use ESB 4.8.0 with WSO2IS 4.5.0.  It is not good idea to downgrade.